# How to save PayPal-Account for future Payments with PayPal REST API and PayPal PHP SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I know that it is possible to save the paypal information of a user for future payments. For example: When a user orders food at an online delivery service, the user can save his paypal information and the next time he orders food he must not login to paypal again.

I think what I am looking for is called "Billing Agreement" within the PayPal REST API. What this does not work without a "Billing Plan", which seems to be for subscritions (recurring payments with the same amount in certain time intervals).

Is Billing Agreement the thing I am looking for?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Information I got from PayPal-Techsupport:

Saving the PayPal-Account-Information for future payments with a different amount (no subscription) is not possible via the REST API.

It is only possible with the "Express Checkout - NVP/SOAP" implementation, which is deprecated since January 1, 2017. You find it under "Reference Transactions":

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

Answer (score 0):

Phantom, you are right! I also get the same reply from PayPal support
I had the same question and when I asked PayPal Support, they replied that we cannot save PayPal Account details for future with a different amount via Rest API. It was only possible with Express Checkout and now it is deprecated. Reference link of Express Checkout is given bellow

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

The above answer was originally posted on https://meansflow.com/213/save-paypal-account-future-payments-with-paypal-rest-paypal